# scp a bunch of files via bash script: there must be a better way

Tags: bash, loops, scp

I currently have the following bash script:

```
for a in `seq 16 75`; 
do scp doneill@server:/mnt/device/folder/numbered_file$a.txt ./; 
done;
```

while this does work, it is very slow.  Each file, the request to the sever takes about 4-7 seconds, then sending the file takes another 3 or so seconds.

Is there a way to do this that involves only 1 command sent to the server (to minimize the time my VPN spends sending receiving each individual command)?  Normally, I would do something like `scp doneill@server:/mnt/device/folder/numbered_file*` but there are many thousands of files in the folder that I don't want to copy.  I need to get only those few (defined by the sequence).

Comment: For future reference, you can use that brace syntax in a `for` statement instead of calling the external `seq` utility: `for a in {16..17}`. You can also do: `for ((a=16; a<=75; a++))`. Including the brace range within the command is the right thing to do in this case, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash:

```
scp doneill@server:/mnt/device/folder/numbered_file{16..75}.txt ./
```

Answer (score 3):

rsync should do the trick: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/

You may have to fiddle a bit with the parameters, but done right, it's probably the fastest way of transferring files over ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work with bash?

```
scp doneill@server:/mnt/device/folder/numbered_file{16..75}.txt ./
```